# Set alpha value of NavigationItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationitem

I try to set the alpha value of a navigationItem to animate the rightBarbutton, but I can´t get it change the value. Any suggestions?

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                  initWithTitle:@"Avbryt" 
                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                  target:self action:@selector(cancelEditing)] autorelease];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.customView.alpha = 0.5;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your code you are trying to set `alpha` for the rightBarButtonItem's `customView`, but you your rightBarButton item doesn't contain any custom view. Isn't it?

`UIBarButtonItem` item is a direct subclass of `UIBarItem` which in turn is a subclass of `NSObject`. So, it is not possible to set its `alpha` directly. You are correct about setting `alpha` for the `customView`, but you have missed to add the customView itself ;-)

Comment: @EmtyStack, Yes that makes a lot of sense. Thanks